# Chained constructers in C# - using intermediate logic

Tags: c#, constructor

From this thread : http://geekswithblogs.net/kaju/archive/2005/12/05/62266.aspx someone asked (in the comments) this question:

> is there any way to do something like
>   this:

```
public FooBar(string fooBar)
{
string[] s = fooBar.split(new char[] { ':' });
this(s[0], s[1]);
}

public Foo(string foo, string bar)
{
...
}
```

Well, I've run into the a situation where I need the same thing. Is it somehow possible? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I meant this

```
public Foo(string fooBar)
{
string[] s = fooBar.split(new char[] { ':' });
this(s[0], s[1]);
}

public Foo(string foo, string bar)
{
...
}
```

Foo is a constructor.

My problem is that I have to do a lot of logic - including some IO stuff - before calling the other constructor.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are Foo and FooBar supposed to both be constructors? Since they are named differently its not entirely clear what you want to do... either Foo should be called FooBar, or Foo should be a method, I guess?

Comment: @ jamietre - yes, I've tried to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly, but:

```
public FooBar(string fooBar)
    : this(fooBar.Split(new char[] { ':' }))
{
}

private FooBar(string[] s)
    : this(s[0], s[1])
{
}

public FooBar(string foo, string bar)
{
...
}
```

Comment: +1 and using `fooBar.Split(':')` directly instead of `new char[] {':'}`

Comment: +1 but OP should be aware that `var foo = new FooBar("hi!");` would result in an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you may need to do "some IO stuff - before calling the other constructor."  Maybe you want a static creation method?

```
public static FooBar LoadFromFile(string fileName)
{
    var foo = "Default";
    var bar = "Other Default";
    // load from the file, do a bunch of logic, 

    return new FooBar(foo, bar);
}
```

Comment: Hi McKay. Actually I ended up doing it in a private static method - to handle exceptions - as you suggested. I accteped Tim Robinson answer since I asked for - and was mostly currious - of the constructor issue, but thanks for you input :)